# string.format, differing length breaks table

Tags: python, list, formatting

I am trying to format a list of lists into a table. It mostly works but if an element is too long it seems to break the table. Any idea why this is happening or what to do to ensure a well formatted table here using this method?

```
 table_data = [['vlan1', '0013.F200.0058', '192.168.2.2'], 
                 ['vlan20', '0013.F200.0058', '192.168.30.2'],
                 ['vlan20', '0010.600a.7026', '192.168.30.4'],
                 ['vlan20', '70ca.9b99.6a82', '192.168.30.1'],
                 ['vlan21', '0013.F200.0058', '192.168.222.222'], 
                 ['vlan100', '0013.F200.0058', '192.168.110.2'],
                 ['vlan2100', '0013.F200.0058', '192.168.222.223']]



for i in table_data:
        interface,mac,ip = i
        print "Internet  {}\t {:>18s}\t{:>7s}\t  {:<8s}".format(ip, mac,'ARPA' ,interface)


Protocol  Address            Hardware Addr         Type   Interface                     
--------  -------            -------------         ----   ---------                     
Internet  192.168.2.2        0013.F200.0058        ARPA   vlan1                 
Internet  192.168.30.2       0013.F200.0058        ARPA   vlan20                
Internet  192.168.30.4       0010.600a.7026        ARPA   vlan20                
Internet  192.168.30.1       70ca.9b99.6a82        ARPA   vlan20                
Internet  192.168.222.222            0013.F200.0058        ARPA   vlan21        
Internet  192.168.110.2      0013.F200.0058        ARPA   vlan100               
Internet  192.168.222.223            0013.F200.0058        ARPA   vlan2100
```

Comment: The problem is more with the use of tabs to separate than with the table being broken. Your example works perfectly if you use fixed-width fields for everything.

Comment: Or, rather, I should have said: "Use a fixed-width field for the first item as well".  Ignore what I said about tabs. I'm not thinking clearly this morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use left aligned format aren't You?
please check this documentation [Format Specification Mini-Language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

```
for i in table_data:
     interface,mac,ip = i
     print '{:<20s}{:<20s}{:<20s}{s}'.format(ip, mac,'ARPA' ,interface)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great, just needed a colon with the s, what confuses me is the drastically different results when I modify the numbers slightly.